# IPTables custom log failing

Tags: iptables, logging, rsyslog

I'm currently trying to split out some of my IPTables logging from kern.log into a file called iptables.log.  Basically, I have several different adapters and I'm logging requests to port 80 on each one.  These rules are working and outputting fine to kern.log.  Here's an example:

```
-A INPUT -d 192.168.100.10 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j LOG --log-prefix "[10010] REQUEST Port 80: " --log-level 7
```

I have done the following to try to split out what I want:

- created an iptables.log files in /var/log that has 644 permissions
- created an `iptables.conf` file in `/etc/rsyslog.d/` with the following contents: `:msg,contains,"[10010] REQUEST Port 80: " -/var/log/iptables.log`
- edited `/etc/rsyslog.conf` to contain the following line: `kern.debug  /var/log/iptables.log`
- restarted rsyslog: `service rsyslog restart`

Despite this, my "[10010]" stuff is still being written to the kern.log file instead of iptables.log.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try renaming `iptables.conf` to `11-iptables.conf`, and restart syslog. There might be other rsyslog filtering rules that got triggered before the `:msg,contains` rule you're using. Prepending `11-` should help your rule to start quite early.

Comment: No dice.  For the record, the only other file in `/etc/rsyslog.d` is `50-Default.conf`.

Comment: Hmmm... if you cut the match string to `"[10010]"`, does it work?

Comment: Or try `startswith` instead of `contains`

Comment: Changed statement to `:msg,startswith,"[10010] " -/var/log/iptables.log` and got nothing....  RAWR

Comment: I feel your pain... last ditch suggestion: Try `:rawmsg,contains` instead of `:msg,contains` ... if this doesn't work, I give up.

Comment: Negative on that one too.  Thanks so much for your help.  I'm going to go self-immolate now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got access to a testing Linux system.

Suddenly I remembered: **`rsyslogd`** writes syslogs as the `syslog` user, not as `root`. (Verified using `ps aux | grep [r]syslog`)

So, `chown syslog.syslog /var/log/iptables.log` should fix the problem.

(Solution tested and working on my system)

Comment: Glad it worked. I decided to not give up because (1) I once had the same problem, and (2) I solved it. But I did not remember exactly how I solved it, hence the several failed attempts in the Q's comments :)